# Online Gdb compiler shows different output than my local computer

Tags: c++, c++14

```
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::max;
using std::vector;

int compute_min_refills(int dist, int tank, vector<int> &stops)
{
    int current_refill, total_refills = 0;
    stops.push_back(dist);
    stops.insert(stops.begin(), 0);
    while (current_refill <= stops.size())
    {
        int last_refill = current_refill;
        while (current_refill <= stops.size() && stops[current_refill + 1] - stops[last_refill] <= tank)
        {
            current_refill++;
            //std::cout << stops[current_refill + 1] << std::endl;
        }
        if (current_refill == last_refill)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (current_refill <= stops.size())
        {
            total_refills++;
        }
    }
    return total_refills;
}

int main()
{
    int d = 0;
    cin >> d;
    int m = 0;
    cin >> m;
    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;

    vector<int> stops(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cin >> stops.at(i);

    cout << compute_min_refills(d, m, stops) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

My local computer running *Manjaro KDE* shows the correct output that is **2** but the *Gdb* compiler shows **0**.

command on my local computer:

> Test case:  500 200 4 100 200 300 400

g++ -pipe -O2 -std=c++14 ./car_fueling.cpp && ./a.out

Comment: You don't initialize `current_refill`, therefore the behaviour of your program is undefined. Compile with `-Wuninitialized`.

Comment: That's why declaring multiple variables in a single statement like `int current_refill, total_refills = 0;` is **a bad idea**.

Comment: Having different results on different computers/compilers is often a good indication that you encounter undefined behavior.

Comment: `while (current_refill <= stops.size() && stops[current_refill + 1] - stops[last_refill] <= tank)` has potentially two out-of-bounds accesses = UB.

Comment: always compile with warnings on (at least `-Wall -Wextra`) in gcc